# What is Prototype's equivalent method to JavaScript's innerHTML property?

Tags: prototypejs, rjs

How can I retrieve HTML content using Prototype?  Or how can I fetch HTML content using RJS?

Comment: innerHTML is a non-standard but widely supported property of DOM element, and should be available in all "modern" browsers, without needing a JS framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('fruit').innerHTML` will give you the inner-html of an element with id fruit.

Access innerHTML through rjs like this: `page["fruit"]["innerHTML"]`

The above code will translate into: `$("fruit").innerHTML;`

Comment: Can i use it as page.select('fruit').innerHTML in rjs? Would it work?

Comment: @Rahul: No, because `select()` returns an array of elements, not a single element. But you can use `page.select("fruit").pluck('innerHTML')` to get an array of each element's `innerHTML`, or you can use one of the Prototype methods that only return one element (if that's what you're looking for) like `down()` or the good old `$()`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$$('div').pluck('innerHTML');
```

Answer (score 0):

As seen on the documentation of Prototype. Use the update() method.
http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/Element/update/

```
$('you_element').update('some fruits here');
```